# Telethon, change offset and length of a text entity given a word to change

Tags: python, entity, offset, telethon

I'm making a bot that replies to a user with the same message but with some words replaced by others.

**Input example:**

*Hi*, **this** is a *keyboard* **example**.

**Excepted output:**

*Hi*, **testing** is a *mouse* **example**. (the word `this` and `keyboard` have been replaced.)

**My output:**

*Hi*, **test**ing is *a mouse* **example**.

I've tried solving this problem changing the offset and length values of `event.message.entities` but i couldn't.

I also tried using `event.get_entities_text()` but couldn't.

So, what's the simplest/best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Telethon v1, you can do this:

```py
text = message.text
replaced = text.replace('this', 'testing')
message.text = replaced
```

This is because `message.text` contains the formatting entities as whatever the `client.parse_mode` says (by default, "markdown" as used by Telegram Desktop), so `text`  would be `__Hi__, **this** is a...`, and replacing `'this'` will keep the formatting intact.

When setting the `message.text`, the library automatically separates it again into raw text plus the entities.

Comment: I haven't really thought about it, thanks.